# MongoDB inserting a record not working as it should

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, multidimensional-array

So, I've been working on this code for some time, but I'm giving up, and reaching out for help from you guys. I've been looking at documentation for MongoDB and PHP, but I can't find anything. What I want to do is take the sample code for inserting a record:

```
$obj = array( "title" => "Calvin and Hobbes", "author" => "Bill Watterson" );
```

And re-purpose is for my project (as shown):

```
    $obj = array( $startCol => $startRow );
```

The thing is that $startCol and $startRow are arrays, and it gives me a problem every time I want to run the document. Is there something ridiculously simple I'm missing here? Thanks in advance.

**Chunk of code that's giving me problems:**

```
$maxRows= count($currentarray); //Outputs 45
$maxCols= count($currentarray[0]); //Outputs 9
$currentRow=1;
$currentCol=1;

$testing = 1;

    do {
    while ($currentCol<$maxCols){
        $startCol[] = $currentarray[0][$currentCol];
        $startRow[] = $currentarray[$currentRow][$currentCol];
        $currentCol++;
    }

    $obj = array( $startCol => $startRow );
    $collection->insert($obj);
    print_r ($collection);
    if ($currentCol==$maxCols)
    $currentCol=1;
    $currentRow++;
    $testing++;
    //echo "<br />";
    } while ($currentRow<$maxRows);
```

Comment: the first thing that jumps out to me is that $collection seems undefined

Comment: Sorry, collection is defined I just didn't post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was getting was with my output statement. So my answer was fairly simple. After, `print_r()` all of my variables I found that I was in fact storing them, but I was calling them incorrectly at the end of the program.